# Is it possible to show the record count as a new column in a matrix report?

Tags: reporting, formula-field

I have a matrix report with two fields on the vertical axis and one (date) on the horizontal axis. It's pretty standard and [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsM4S.png).
I turn to you for advice. Any way to have the record count as a separate column to the right of the total ARR, instead of a row below it?

Any trick, workaround, anything?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

All summarized fields would be displayed one below the other in Matirx Report, And am Not sure about Matrix Report but you can try a Summary Report for a separate display of Record count.